# how to fetch data from Api folder in next.js

Tags: api, next.js

I"m facing this problem, I store my submitted data in api folder from a page and i successfully can store it and when i console.log it I can see the data but the problem is when I try fetch it to a page where I want show all this data then I didn't get any result, it's shows empty object:

this is the page from where I submitted data to api folder/page

```
      const handleSubmitAllData = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const allData = {
          addStory,
          selectedVideoUrl,
        };
        console.log("AllNftData:", allData);
        try {
          const { data } = await axios({
            url: "/api/uploadNftData",
            method: "POST",
            data: allData,
          });
          console.log("response Data", data);
        } catch (error) {
          console.log("Error", error);
        }
        router.push("/template/marketplace");
      };

this is the api page where store data, when console.log the data i see it that's means it's working
this is code of api page

    const { log } = console;
    export default function teamAdd(req, res) {
      if (req.method === "POST") {
        const nftData = req.body;
        log("Req payload", nftData);
        res.json(nftData);
      }
      return res.status(500).json({
        msg: "this needs to be post request",
      });
    }

and this is page where I try to fetch this store data from api. this is code , it's not working. I try so many time but it's always comes out with not data
function page() {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [comments, setComments] = useState([]);
  const fetchComments = async () => {
    const response = await fetch("/api/uploadNftData");
    const data = await response.json();
    setComments(data);
    console.log(data);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);
    fetch("/api/uploadNftData", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({}),
    })
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
        return res.json();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
        setData(data);
        setLoading(false);
      })
      .catch((error) => {});
  }, []);

  if (isLoading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
  if (!data) return <p>No profile data</p>;
  return (
    <>
      <Main>
        <Templatepage>
          <TemplateHeader />
          <Herosec>
            marketplace
            <Box
              sx={{
                background: "#000",
                height: "200px",
                width: "200px",
                margin: "80px",
              }}
            >
              <h1 style={{ color: "#fff" }}>{data.addStory}</h1>
              <p style={{ color: "#fff" }}>{data.selectedVideoUrl}</p>
            </Box>
          </Herosec>
        </Templatepage>
      </Main>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: are you saving the data somewhere? it looks like the API endpoint returns the data sent to it, and in the second case you're sending an empty object `{}` so it returns that.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you try to update the dependency array of the useEffect with data

```
  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);
    fetch("/api/uploadNftData", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({}),
    })
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
        return res.json();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
        setData(data);
        setLoading(false);
      })
      .catch((error) => {});
  }, [data]);
```

And I would change the default state of

```
const [data, setData] = useState(null);
```

to something more reliable like some custom interface or type.

Comment: it's still not working when I add [data] it's kind of start loop and the loop never finish

Answer (score 0):

You can try to verify if data is null in `useEffect` and then do the request.

It should look something like this:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if(data === null){
      setLoading(true);
      fetch("/api/uploadNftData", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({}),
      })
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
        return res.json();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
        setData(data);
        setLoading(false);
      })
      .catch((error) => {});
    }
  }, [data]);
```